# I cannot add a video in Next Typescript

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, types

[image: So this is the overall structure of the code]

The Error: ./public/videos/thevid.mp4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Actions I did:

I used multiple npm packages like next-video or react-video.

I also declared the .mp4 type in the .d.ts file

Comment: Please post *code* not pictures of code.

Comment: Oh my bad, just wanted to show everything because I also want to make sure it's in the right directory.

The code: 

import myVid from '/public/videos/thevid.mp4'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Image 
    src={BackGround}
    alt='background image'
    objectFit='responsive'
    layout='fill'
    />
    
    <video 
    src={require('/public/videos/thevid.mp4')}
    />
    

    </div>
  )
}

Comment: Have you tried to call `const video = require('/public/videos/thevid.mp4')` and then do `<video src={video} />` Also try to remove `/public` and just do `/video/thevid.mp4`